# Unable to locate element Selenium, though element present in page source

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, selector

I am new to using Scrapy+Selenium. My spider is as follows:

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hotel"
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.booking.com/']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/archana-residency.en-gb.html'
    ]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//strong[contains(@class, "b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker") and contains(@class, "rooms-table-room-price") and contains(@class, "red-actual-rack-rate")]')
        print(next)
        try:
            next.click()
            filename = 'example.txt'
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(next.text)
        except:
            pass

        self.driver.close()
```

But I get these logs everytime:

```
2016-06-09 16:38:04 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection]    DEBUG: Finished Request
2016-06-09 16:38:04 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET      http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/archana-residency.en-gb.html> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-   packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File    "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/scrapy_project/scrapy_project/spiders/stackoverflow_spider.py", line 19, in parse
next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//strong[contains(@class, "b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker") and contains(@class, "rooms-table-room-price")]')
File "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 745, in find_element
{'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
File "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/Nik/Desktop/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in      check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:    {"method":"xpath","selector":"//strong[contains(@class, \"b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker\") and contains(@class, \"rooms-table-room-price\")]"}


<strong
  data-price-without-addons="Rs.&nbsp;3,470"
  data-price-with-parking=""
  data-price-with-internet=""
  data-price-with-internet-parking=""
  class=" b-tooltip-with-price-breakdown-tracker rooms-table-room-price       red-actual-rack-rate"
  title=""
>
 Rs.&nbsp;3,470
 </strong>
```

I have also tried "driver.find_element_by_css_selector" but it still gives that error. I want to know is there something wrong what xpaths I use or there is something that I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Hi guys, have found a soution to this. To those who are facing the problem like mine, please use WebdriverWait as it waits for specified time so that the page make all the calls that it has to make so that the data is finally available. Example:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "example class name"))
        )
```

Comment: Are you sure that you use correct `XPath`? Provide an `HTML` code for target element

Comment: @Andersson thanks for the swift reply. I have edited the HTML as well. Now can you please suggest. For complete HTML can you please view the page source once.

Comment: is that element inside a frame element?

Comment: @Bryan Thanks.  Viewing the page source doesn't show frame element, can that be defined through javascript.